# Move Controls On Winforms

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have 2 picture boxes.

**First size** is Width:1000 Height:250

**second** is Widht:1000 Height:25

and I have 3 threads

One of this thread is

```
Thread ThreadSample;

private void FrmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ThreadSample= new Thread(new ThreadStart(MyMethod));
   ThreadSample.Start();
}
void MyMethod()
{
   int YValue=GetY();//I have a function for get Intege
   while (true)
   {
      picurebox2.Invoke(new Action(() => picturebox2.Location=new Point(0,YValue)));
      Thread.Sleep(1);
   }
}
```

It is slow.

What is the fastest way move control on runtime?

Comment: Your thread method spends most of time in GUI thread (via `Invoke`). What's the point to use it at all?

Comment: As suggested, your multi-threading is pointless.  Just use a WinForms Timer and move the control in the Tick event handler.  If you want animation then WPF would be a better option than WinForms but you're still not going to get some perfectly smooth and fast.

Comment: This is for a machine.After Machine send me value I am set location of  control

Comment: @user3247640: but you're setting the same location in an endless loop, and `GetY` called just once. This doesn't make a sense.

Comment: @Dennis Sorry I cut some code.GetY() is in the while

Comment: The smallest usable value you can pass to Sleep() is 15.  Which is already much faster than a human eye can ever perceive so is just a waste of cpu cycles that only make your program slow.  A practical value is 46 which is on the edge of perception, 31 is the next lower good value.  Be sure to use proper Y increments to get your desired target speed, you probably punted for increments of 1 right now which of course makes it very slow moving.  Never use a thread, use a Timer.